# How to use AsyncTask manager with this code?

Tags: android

I have this code and i would like to use asyncTask manager with this to let the user know something is happening. How would i allow this to happen with this snippet of code. i cant seem to figure it out. I know the asyncTask will be better than using a Hanlder. Or would it?
But anyway here is an example. if anyone can help out. Please do. Thanks.

```
     enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             item = book.getText().toString();
             searchForItem();


        }
    });
```

i would like to run this method with a progress dialog spinner letting the user know something is happening. How do i do this, and stop the spinner when the web page is loaded?

Here is my SearchForItem().

```
    public void searchForBook(){

    String url = "www.example.com";
    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.shopView);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new BookLookupbrowser());
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a child class of [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Override the three main methods, `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute`, `doInBackground`.
2. In `onPreExecute`, start your `ProgessDialog`.
3. In `doInBackground`, run your `searchForBook()` method.
4. In `onPostExecute`, dismiss your `ProgressDialog`.
5. If you need functionality for cancelling your `AsyncTask`, more methods exist and are well documented in the documentation.
6. With your new `AsyncTask` subclass, start it in the `onClick` method from your first snippet.
7. If any of this doesn't make sense, refer to [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/painless-threading.html) in the Android Documentation, as it is extremely helpful.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks alot youve been extremeply helpful!. one more question. How does the onPostExecute know when the webpage is fully loaded?

Comment: The lifecycle handler of the AsyncTask will call it when the doInBackground method is complete.

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example for something like i have above? Hope im not asking for to much.

Comment: If you extend AsycTask, and follow the steps I placed above, you should be able to call execute() on an instance of your AsyncTask you create in your onClick handler.

Comment: So what should doInBackground method return? for my case?

Comment: It will return nothing, because you have nothing to return.  You may return null.